# How to integrate Azure AD authentication in .NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-3.1

I am currently logging to my .net core application hosted in Azure with database authentication. Now, I want to integrate Azure AD authentication to my application.
Can anyone guide me through how to set this?

Comment: Start with looking at Microsoft authentication protocols supported by azure - auth, implicit etc. I think you would probably be using authorization code flow. Start from there then implement open Id connect on top of that. There is good literature by Microsoft on the examples.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp) is an example quickstart by Microsoft.